# Read line by line and skip under condition when using numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to define a function that opens a txt file, make it a `N*3` matrix. However, lines that don't match certain conditions should be skipped and an error message should be displayed before continuing to read the lines.

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
def dataLoad(filename):
    data=np.loadtxt(filename)
    return data
```

So I have the matrix but now I would like to read it line by line, skip when conditions are not met, display an error message that explains what the error is and at what line it occurred, and continue.

The conditions are:
• The first column must be a number between 10 and 60.
• The second column must be a positive number.
• The third column must be 1,2,3 or 4.

## Edit

I've tried:

```
import numpy as np
def dataLoad(filename):
    data=np.loadtxt(filename)
    for row in data:
        if (row[0] < 10) or (row[0] > 60):
            print("Temperature is out of range")
            continue
        elif (row[1]<0):
            print("Growth rate is negative")
            continue
        elif (row[2]!=1) or (row[2]!=2) or (row[2]!=3) or (row[2]!=4):
            print("Bacteria is not 1, 2, 3 or 4")
            continue
    return data
```

But it gives me all the error messages at the beginning, and then all the rows including the ones that should be excluded.

## Edit 2

I have also tried to read the file line by line using:

```
data = open("test.txt", "r")
line = data.readline()
if (line[0] < 10) or (line[0] > 60):
    print("Temperature is out of range")
elif (line[1]<0):
    print("Growth rate is negative")
elif (line[2]!=1) or (line[2]!=2) or (line[2]!=3) or (line[2]!=4):
    print("Bacteria is not 1, 2, 3 or 4")
```

I know it wouldn't delete the rows but at least I was hoping it would give me the error messages for the right rows. But it returns:

```
 if (line[0] < 10) or (line[0] > 60):

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Comment: You have the conditions, you have the matrix. What stops you from checking if each row satisfies these conditions? You can iterate over the rows of your matrix and check everything

Comment: Rather than loading entire text iterate over each row and add the row if only your criteria is met

Comment: I have tried this: 
import numpy as np
def dataLoad(filename):
    data=np.loadtxt(filename)
    for row in data:
        if (row[0] < 10) or (row[0] > 60):
            print("Temperature is out of range")
            continue
        elif (row[1]<0):
            print("Growth rate is negative")
            continue
        elif (row[2]!=1) or (row[2]!=2) or (row[2]!=3) or (row[2]!=4):
            print("Bacteria is not 1, 2, 3 or 4.")
            continue
    return data
print(dataLoad("test.txt")) 
But it doesn't seem to remove the rows

Comment: In your edit the `data=np.loadtxt(filename)` reads the entire file in, which is why you get all the rows. The error messages are printed afterwards (and printing them doesn't remove anything).

Comment: Thanks for the comments. How can I read only the rows? I think there's something like "open data as f" but I can't example that resemble my case enough for me to apply it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is me again:) this code is the fixed verion of the Edit 2 in question description:

```
data = open("test.txt", "r").readlines()
for raw_line in range(len(data)):
    line = [int(n) for n in data[raw_line].split(' ')]# this splits the "1 2 3" to ['1','2','3'] and then, makes them integer([1,2,3])
    if (line[0] < 10) or (line[0] > 60):
        print("Temperature is out of range in row",raw_line)
    elif (line[1]<0):
        print("Growth rate is negative in row",raw_line)
    elif (line[2]!=1) or (line[2]!=2) or (line[2]!=3) or (line[2]!=4):
        print("Bacteria is not 1, 2, 3 or 4 in row",raw_line)
```

PS: I assume that each line of test.txt's format is exactly "a b c" where a,b and c are numbers. if it's different, let me know to fix it

PPS: as you know, this code won't remove the invalid rows and just prints the error messages

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the code that you need. let me know if I got anything wrong.

```
import numpy as np

def dataLoad(filename):
    #opening and reading the data file
    file=open(filename,'r').readline()
    #creating the numpy matrix object
    data=np.matrix(file)

    print('raw data:',data)

    #checking the conditions
    #... for first column
    i=0
    while(i<len(data)):
        if data.item(i,0)<10 or 60<data.item(i,0):
            print('error message')
            print('removed',data[i])
            data=np.delete(data,(i),axis=0)
        else:
            i+=1

    print('data after checking 1st condition:',data)

    #... for second column
    i=0
    while(i<len(data)):
        if data.item(i,1)<0:
            print('error message')
            print('removed',data[i])
            data=np.delete(data,(i),axis=0)
        else:
            i+=1

    print('data after checking the 2nd condition:',data)

    #... for third column
    i=0
    while(i<len(data)):
        if data.item(i,2) not in (1,2,3,4):
            print('error message')
            print('removed',data[i])
            data=np.delete(data,(i),axis=0)
        else:
            i+=1

    print('data after checking the 3rd condition:',data)
    return data

print(dataLoad('test.txt'))
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. When I run this code, I get the following: 
  File "<ipython-input-59-d3d71b5bba19>", line 15, in dataLoad
    if data.item(1,i)<0:

IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1

Comment: @Maylis your welcome. I just edited and tested the new code. this should work. if not, let me know.

Comment: @Maylis I just read the question edit. in previous version the invalid row would not be removed. in this version, it is. let me know if this code works or not :)

Comment: Now it prints "error message []". The first condition contains a mistake, the rows should be deleted if the value of the first column is less than 10 or greater than 60. I corrected this, and now it prints [[39.122    0.81021  1.     ]]
[[39.122    0.81021  1.     ]]
Which is still too little... Thank you!

Comment: @Maylis hi. your welcome. I edited the code again for the "less than 10 or greater than 60" part. but as I get from your comment, this code has still some issues. could you explain it more?(I mean, please give me a test.txt row that has been incorrectly removed from data or not removed, but it should be)

Comment: Thanks for helping out. So with the edited code, it only prints: [[39.122 0.81021 1. ]] [[39.122 0.81021 1. ]]. However in total the original file has 69 rows and only a few of them should be removed (around 8). For example, I should have these rows: [39.122 0.81021 1] [13.534 0.5742 1] [56.137 0.20517 1] [50.019 0.4754 1]

Comment: @Maylis thats strange. cause I gave this rows to my program with some correct and incorrect rows around them, and I'm getting the correct rows(including the rows you said and one example correct row, and dis-including the invalid rows). are you sure that you are running this code or you saw the full output? because this code seems to be correct

Comment: @Maylis also try this: "1 2 3;7,8,9;13.534,0.5742,1;11,1,3;56.137,0.20517,1;4,5,6;50.019,0.4754,1" as the input data in test.txt and let me know if you got the correct output or not

Comment: I have copy pasted your full code and tried with a .txt that contains the number you gave me and it returned "error message []". I don't know what's wrong. Someone suggested that I try to iterate over each row and only add the row if the condition is met. Maybe looking into that would work better?

Comment: @Maylis both ways would not work if there is something wrong on your computer. I tried with same data, and it works for me. I think there is a little issue that makes the problem. e.g you are not getting the full output, or you forgot to save the code,... is there an other computer that you can try on it? mine is a macos 10.14.2 with python3.7.2 and numpy 1.16. also I added some "log prints"(for debugging) on the code after checking each condition. try again with the test.txt in previous comments and with that prints in the code, and tell me witch part is not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is you are not mutating data once the condition is satisfied. Something like the code below should help solve your problem:

```
import numpy as np
def dataLoad(filename):
    data=np.loadtxt(filename)
    retdata = []
    for row in data:
        if (row[0] < 10) or (row[0] > 60):
            print("Temperature is out of range")
            continue
        elif (row[1]<0):
            print("Growth rate is negative")
            continue
        elif (row[2]!=1) or (row[2]!=2) or (row[2]!=3) or (row[2]!=4):
            print("Bacteria is not 1, 2, 3 or 4")
            continue
    retdata.append(row)
    return retdata
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However when I run the code, it only prints the error messages, it doesn't print the correct rows. I have tried to replace "continue" with pass" but it gives me the same result. Any idea?